# Best Practice to Use Objects to Optimize Memory Management for C# Web API

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

There are a couple of ways we can create objects and access the object's properties & methods in C#.

But I couldn't decide which is recommended approach to handle good memory management for C# Web API environment .

Let said I have a Person class as shown below:

```
public class Person 
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Which scenario below consider is the best practice to create & use objects for a better memory management.

Scenario 1: Use constructor

```
public class MembershipManager
{
   private readonly Person _person;

   public MembershipManager()
   {
      _person = new Person();
   }

    public Person GetPerson(string name)
    { 
       /*Access methods or properties using [_person] object*/
    }
}
```

Scenario 2: USING statement (implement with IDisposable)

```
public class MembershipManager
{
   public Person GetPerson(string name)
   {
    using(var pm = new Person())
    {
      /*Access methods or properties using [pm] object*/
    }
   }
}
```

Scenario 3: Create new objects (on every API call)

```
public class MembershipManager
{
  public Person GetPerson(string name)
  {
       Person person = new Person();
       /*Access methods or properties using [person] object*/
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with memory management?

Comment: What are you really disposing of from Person in the second scenario?  I understand that memory is a scarce and precious resource, but this feels like you're trying to write C# as if it were C++.  The vast majority of the time, you can rely on the garbage collector to manage all of this for you.  The exception would be if you were passing around a large number of graphics objects, but, unless you example is truly a "toy" problem, it's trivial to manage POCOs.